# OOP in python version 3.5?

Tags: oop, python-3.x

I was using python 2.7 and then I've heard that there is an OOP in python 3.5 so I started to use this version but still I couldn't understand how to create classes in python 3.5?
I mean how the coding of the class looks like?

Comment: 2.7 supports OOP as well. I recommend Googling some tutorials.

Comment: There is *"an OOP"* in 2.7, too. I'd recommend you find an introductory tutorial, see e.g. http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html :

The simplest form of class definition looks like this:

```
class ClassName:
    <statement-1>
    .
    .
    .
    <statement-N>
```